# Polymer google-map-marker not shown in Meteor app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, polymer, google-maps-markers

I have a Meteor app that has a google-map web component (Polymer) installed with Bower. It works great, but when I try to include google-map-marker elements on it, they don't show up.

This is the code of the map:

```
<style>
        google-map {
            width: 500px;
            height: 300px;                
        }
</style>  
<google-map disable-default-ui latitude="37.77493" longitude="-122.41942" fit-to-markers>
      <google-map-marker latitude="37.779" longitude="-122.3892"></google-map-marker>
      <google-map-marker latitude="37.777" longitude="-122.38911"></google-map-marker>
</google-map>
```

I tried including a link to the google-map-marker.html as well in my main html file, as well as google-apis, polymer and webcomponents.js, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Also, I tried several order of the links and nothing changed the problem:

```
<head>    
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/google-map/google-map-marker.html">        
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/google-map/google-map.html">    
</head>
```

I'm using [google-map web component version 1.0.3](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-map/components/google-map/).

Is it something to do with Meteor's load order?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine for me, I did not use Meteor, though. Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Maria Nope, nothing. I also checked that everything I need is being loaded in the sources tab, and it does. The bower_components is located in my Public folder.

Comment: Any solution? I'm not user meteor, but i'm having the same problem.